# All SSD file server cache on ram, is it safe?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, cache

I am running a Dell optiplex 790 , i5 2400, 8gb ram (now 16GB), on a 870 evo 250gb boot drive, 1&4tb 870 qvo ssds for storage, Linux Mint as base OS.

I'm worried about ram failing although no signs of trouble, I can see the cache build up to about 13.5/80(ish)% (during a 14GB transfer) of available ram. Is this a safe setup? Are there alternatives I should consider? I'm not using ZFS on account of the new requirements being I need TPM 2.0. Just wanna see if there's any other little tweaks I should look into.

All this computer does is store and serve data. Very rarely do i send data to it, but when i do, it's in the multi-gigabyte range in any instance.

Update: i did previously hit a drop in connection while transferring a large amount of data to the server and i put this down to the quality of the hardware in the client device (Unihertz Jelly Star) being too weak to sustain the transmission of data over an extended period of time, the rest of the client end devices i use handle transfers without a sweat (previously a galaxy S10e and MANY windows and Linux based machines) on the Jelly star, it was moving data at around 2MB/second, hence the suspicion of weak hardware, combined with a slower connection speed/protocol over wifi. This was confirmed with a bulk transfer test via a galaxy A03S.

I doubled the ram to 16GB (soon to be 32GB) to reduce the chances of any performance issues.
-read/write dips were noticeable in previous iterations of the setup in shuttle XS35 (v1 & v3) machines, but no drops in connection to my knowledge as highlighted above. i suspect this was down to limitations of the Atom CPU and ram as a whole hence the switch and consolidation into a dell rig.

My real concern here is while it appears that the computer in the server sole is fine holding the cached data in ram, I want some kind of reassurance that it is safe in doing so, if not i would absolutely love to find a solution that clears the cache when transfers complete after a set time, rather than having a cronjob do it automatically, say for example, every 30 minutes.
Instead, having the computer say to itself: "okay, no clients have asked for this data as of 45 minutes ago, time to clear it out of the ram".

The concern is becoming greater with the eventual NIC upgrade to 2.5GBE, however i don't see it becoming an issue, just wanting to slap together a reliable and very responsive setup that will absolutely slap the s*** out of USB based network shares, and so far this has already been achieved under a 1GBE NIC, but i'm not done there clearly hence the desire for a faster network connection between client and server.

I apologize for the poor spelling and punctuation, I am part Australian (25%)/New Zealand (remainder) so language can be crude at the best of times.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit all-over-the-place.

Caching disk reads is a normal part of most OS's now - this behavior is normal and to be expected.

It is possible for data to get corrupted in RAM and then corrupt whats on disk - but its more likely to cause segfaults.

The alternative here is to test the RAM (eg., using memtest86) and replace it if it's faulty. I don't think a filesystem like ZFS will help here - indeed there was a lot of hand waving some time ago about ZFS requiring ECC memory to safeguard against memory corruption.